# Can't set a,b in cv2.convertScaleAbs for a linear tranform of the input

Tags: python, opencv

I'm learning OpenCV, and looking at [convertScaleAbs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga3460e9c9f37b563ab9dd550c4d8c4e7d) to transform the original values to the range [0,255], quite similar to what [normalize](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd) do in the mode `NORM_MINMAX`.

As far as I understand, values are transformed according to y = a*x + b, then the resulting values are clipped and converted to uint8. If this is correct, then selecting a and b this way:

```
a = (255.0 - 0) / (x_max - x_min)
b = -x_min * a
```

should linearly transform the original values to [0,255] and the final step, the clipping, should not change the values (only the type). However I cannot obtain this correct result with the a and b values above. I create random original values, then show the result of `normalize` (the ones expected), then the results of `convertScaleAbs` (wrong, everything converted to 255):

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import random as rnd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

x_values = range(100)
y_values = [None]*3

# Original values
a,b = rnd.randint(0,10), rnd.randint(0,1e4)
y_values[0] = np.array([a*i+b for i in x_values])
np.random.shuffle(y_values[0])

# Transformed values, fist method
y_values[1] = np.zeros(y_values[0].shape)
y_values[1] = cv2.normalize(
    y_values[0], y_values[1],
    0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8U)

# Transformed values, alternate method
ymin, ymax = y_values[0].min(), y_values[0].max()
a = (255.0 - 0) / (ymax - ymin)
b = -ymin * a
y_values[2] = cv2.convertScaleAbs(y_values[0], a, b)

# Check visually
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1, figsize=(6,4), sharex=True)
for i,values in enumerate(y_values):
    ax[i].set_ylim(y_values[i].min(), y_values[i].max())
    ax[i].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8)
    ax[i].set_title(titles[i], fontsize=8)
    ax[i].grid(axis='both', ls=':')
    ax[i].scatter(x_values, y_values[i], marker='.', s=1)
fig.tight_layout()

plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=5)
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Shouldn't b = -x_min * a ?

Comment: @SarthakRout: Thanks for correcting (Itested many cases, this is a leftover). However the result is the same with *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation at [convertScaleAbs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga3460e9c9f37b563ab9dd550c4d8c4e7d), the second argument to the function should be the destination matrix: y_values[2] here.

After changing to
`y_values[2] = cv2.convertScaleAbs(y_values[0], y_values[2], a, b)`
, it seems fine now:
[image]